How to search for a sequence of values in a column PySpark
I have a dataframe with a "time" column, and a "values" column. Example:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Example").getOrCreate()

v = [1,4,1,12,4,2,1,2,5,6,2,2,4,4,7,3,3,4,7,3]
t = range(0, len(v))

data = list(zip(t, v))
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["time", "values"])

df.show()

+----+------+
|time|values|
+----+------+
|   0|     1|
|   1|     4|
|   2|     1|
|   3|    12|
|   4|     4|
|   5|     2|
|   6|     1|
|   7|     2|
|   8|     5|
|   9|     6|
|  10|     2|
|  11|     2|
|  12|     4|
|  13|     4|
|  14|     7|
|  15|     3|
|  16|     3|
|  17|     4|
|  18|     7|
|  19|     3|
+----+------+

And I have a sequence of values
seq = [4,7,3,3]
I need to find where in my "values" column I can find this sequences of values seq, i.e. the "time" when my sequence starts. In my example it would be at "time" ==13
Please take into account the dataframe I'm using is more than 70 millions rows, and the sequence I have is around 3 thousands elements, so computing resources efficiency is needed for the problem
I tried brute force work-arounds, for example by searching the first element in "values", generating a new column with lag, that allows me to search for the second term in a row where the laged first term is confirmed, and repeat the operation, each time confirming the new value and the precedent value. Sadly my resources aren't enough and spark is giving out OOM (Out Of Merory) errors, thus a more efficient method is needed
I also tried choping the data, but I think a good answer to this question is much interesting than manually choping data

You probably need a Spark-based implementation of a string-searching algorithm like Boyer-Moore. I found this article but that looks like some work to implement it.

Why string searching? I'm looking for numerical values that follow each other in the table rows, I don't understand the connection

The df is like a large string (that's because the order in the column time is important) and the seq is the substring that you are looking for in the large string.

I see, it could be an interesting approach, I'll look into it thank you

You can use a window with the collect_list function to generate a column with lists of 4 consecutive rows. The answer would then be as follows.
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list, col, lit
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

seq = [4,7,3,3]

windowSpec = Window.orderBy("time").rangeBetween(0, len(seq) - 1)

v = [1,4,1,12,4,2,1,2,5,6,2,2,4,4,7,3,3,4,7,3]
t = range(0, len(v))

data = list(zip(t, v))
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["time", "values"]) \
    .withColumn("values_list", collect_list("values").over(windowSpec))

df = df.filter(col("values_list") == lit(seq))

df.show()

This then gives you the answer:
+----+------+------------+
|time|values| values_list|
+----+------+------------+
|  13|     4|[4, 7, 3, 3]|
+----+------+------------+

Since you indicate it's not quick enough, maybe try whether the following works, combining your shifted solution with a single condition and adding all the columns in the select (not a withColumn). This could improve performance.
from pyspark.sql.functions import lead, lit, col 
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

seq = [4, 7, 3, 3]

windowSpec = Window.orderBy("time")

v = [1,4,1,12,4,2,1,2,5,6,2,2,4,4,7,3,3,4,7,3]
t = range(0, len(v))

data = list(zip(t, v))
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["time", "values"])

shifted_cols = [lead("values", i).over(windowSpec).alias(f"shift_{i}") for i, val in enumerate(seq)]

df_shifted = df.select("time", "values", *shifted_cols)

condition = lit(True)
for i, value in enumerate(seq):
    condition = condition & (col(f"shift_{i}") == lit(value))

df_filtered = df_shifted.filter(condition)

df_filtered.show()

Giving the answer:
+----+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|time|values|shift_0|shift_1|shift_2|shift_3|
+----+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  13|     4|      4|      7|      3|      3|
+----+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+


I tried this method, but with 70+ millions rows, and a sequence of 3k elements to check, this operation is extremely slow. I tried it but had to stop it after 2h of computing without results yet.
With smaller datasets this is a working solution tho

I added another solution that might improve performance, curious to hear how this works at your scale.

I get an error on line ---> 17 df_filtered = df_shifted.filter(condition)
An error is raised on the filter: "NOT_COLUMN_OR_STR"
When I try to print condition, I get an error  An error occurred while calling o148421.toString

Is that for the exact code I sent or only for your data? Because maybe it doesn't like such a long condition.

After looking into it I confirm, your exact example works, but it cannot handle so many conditions when tried on this magnitude of data. Something breaks at some point of the condition building
